# why do i get error from clang but not with xcode's default compiler when i build the follow code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, clang

```
func(char * buff)
{
    if (buff == NULL || buff <= 0)
    {
       //do some things
    }
}
```

> from clang 4.0:  "Ordered comparison between pointer and zero."
>
> from xcode 8:    "build successful"

```
i guess this might be the error that could be change to a warning.
What should i do if i want to close this error in clang?
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Xcode allows that code.

The code itself doesn't make any sense. A pointer is not a signed value, so checking to see if the pointer is 0 or negative is nonsensical.

You can fix it by getting rid of the second part of that if statement. It doesn't make sense.

BTW, using "func" in Objective-C code is very confusing. That is the label for functions in Swift. At first I could not make any sense out of your code because I saw the `func` and assumed it was Swift, but it did not make sense as Swift.